# All tags one level, order group and sort in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an issue with an XML (salesorder). I import an file (csv) with a XML-structure.
The tool I used automatic creates a XML from this file with the same structure. All tags are on the same level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDER>
<ENV>
    <SenderCode>1234</SenderCode>
    <Test>N</Test>
</ENV>
<HDR>
    <OrderNumber>100</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
</HDR>
<ROW>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <Article>A</Article>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
    <Article>B</Article>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
    <Article>C</Article>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <LineNumber>4</LineNumber>
    <Article>D</Article>
</ROW>
<HDR>
    <OrderNumber>101</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
</HDR>
<ROW>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <Article>E</Article>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
    <Article>F</Article>
</ROW>
</ORDER>
```

The output i need is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDER>
  <ENV>
    <SenderCode>1234</SenderCode>
    <Test>N</Test>
  </ENV>
  <HDR>
    <OrderNumber>100</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
    <ROW>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <Article>A</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <Article>B</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
      <Article>C</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <LineNumber>4</LineNumber>
      <Article>D</Article>
    </ROW>
  </HDR>
  <ENV>
    <SenderCode>1234</SenderCode>
    <Test>N</Test>
  </ENV>
  <HDR>
    <OrderNumber>101</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
    <ROW>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <Article>E</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <Article>F</Article>
    </ROW>
  </HDR>
</ORDER>
```

How could I do this with XSLT? When I tried this, all six `ROW` tags are under both `HDR`(1) and `HDR`(2).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDER>
<ENV>
    <SenderCode>1234</SenderCode>
    <Test>N</Test>
</ENV>
<HDR>
    <OrderNumber>100</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <Article>A</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Article>B</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
        <Article>C</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>4</LineNumber>
        <Article>D</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <Article>E</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Article>F</Article>
    </ROW>
</HDR>
<ENV>
    <SenderCode>1234</SenderCode>
    <Test>N</Test>
</ENV>
<HDR>
    <OrderNumber>101</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <Article>A</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Article>B</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
        <Article>C</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>4</LineNumber>
        <Article>D</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <Article>E</Article>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Article>F</Article>
    </ROW>
</HDR>
</ORDER>
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Also, perhaps you can add a bit of data to your samples, as it is not clear whether your "ENV" and "HDR" elements are empty or not in the input XML, and if not, what should happen to the data in the output. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the XSLT you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This transform will do what you ask. It uses a key to identify all the `ROW` elements immediately following each `HDR`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="row-by-hdr-id" match="ROW" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::HDR[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/ORDER">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="HDR"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="HDR">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::ENV"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row-by-hdr-id', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ORDER>
   <ENV>
      <SenderCode>1234</SenderCode>
      <Test>N</Test>
   </ENV>
   <HDR>
      <OrderNumber>100</OrderNumber>
      <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
      <ROW>
         <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
         <Article>A</Article>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
         <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
         <Article>B</Article>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
         <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
         <Article>C</Article>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
         <LineNumber>4</LineNumber>
         <Article>D</Article>
      </ROW>
   </HDR>
   <ENV>
      <SenderCode>1234</SenderCode>
      <Test>N</Test>
   </ENV>
   <HDR>
      <OrderNumber>101</OrderNumber>
      <OrderDate>201206080000</OrderDate>
      <ROW>
         <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
         <Article>E</Article>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
         <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
         <Article>F</Article>
      </ROW>
   </HDR>
</ORDER>
```